# regular expression on method Pattern.compile()

Tags: java, regex, parsing

i have to create a regular expression to put into the method Pattern.compile(regex);
My regex has to allow integer (without 0 at the beginning of the number),a sequence of numbers and char (A-Za-z),but the problem is the third point: a string that must begin and end with the char ' " ', must avoid the chars backslash (unless there isn't one other backslash) and the char '"' (unless there is before a backslash)

but i don't understand how to do the second point ( i have met a lot of errors), this is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*)|"
            + "(0(?![0-9])|([1-9]+)([0-9]*))|" //"?!" è una asserzione : " se la condizione tra parentesi è vera non considerare lo zero
            + "([\"]{1}(([\\\\][^\"\\][\\\"])*)[\"]{1})" 
            + "|(\\s+)").matcher(args[0]);// \s = [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
    System.out.println("Input: " + args[0]); //println va a capo dopo la stampa
    while (matcher.lookingAt()) {
        System.out.print("Lexeme '" + matcher.group() + "'"); //non va a capo dopo la stampa
        System.out.println(" group " + ExampleLexer.getGroup(matcher));
        matcher.region(matcher.end(), matcher.regionEnd());
    }

     //attenzione: matcher.hitEnd() restituisce true se il matcher arriva in fondo
     //all'input anche se l'ultimo match non ha avuto successo, quindi funziona solo
     //per espressioni regolari "semplici"
    if (matcher.regionStart() == matcher.regionEnd())
        System.out.println("All lexems succesfully matched");
    else {
        System.err.print("Unmatched lexem ");
        matcher.usePattern(Pattern.compile(".*"));
        matcher.lookingAt();
        System.err.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: The second point being "_,a sequence of numbers _" ? `\d+` ? Please provide a [mcve]. Using some enumeration for each requirements would be more readable. And of course, you have a lot of errors, but don't mention which one. If this is to complex to explain better that this at least add an example (input/output)

Comment: thanks for asking:) my problem is the third point! every string like this: "\\hello\"" has to become \hello"      but i don't know how to do it! i mean the backslash and the "  muest be  banned but \\ and \" must be agreeded..

Comment: the error is : Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 89
([a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*)|(0(?![0-9])|([1-9]+)([0-9]*))|(["]{1}([(\(?=\|\"))][^\"])*)["]{1})|(\s+)
                                                                                         ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at lab05_12_04.ExampleLexer.main(ExampleLexer.java:18)

Comment: I will not read the regex (you should understand why ;) ) but you forgot a `)` to close a group. PS: [edit] the question with that information.

Comment: as you can see i have changed the third line of my regular expression, but still no work..

Comment: yeah, sorry :') but the problem is that everytime the syntax is correct the output will be " unmtched lexem"

Comment: Please... [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
"\"(\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\""            // (1)
"\"(\\\\[\"\\\\]|[^\"\\\\])*\""     // (2)
```

- quote
- zero or more times `(`...`)*`

  - either backslash `\` followed by (1) any char `.` / (2) any non-quote/non-backslash
  - or `|` not a quote, not a backslash `[^` ... `]`
- quote

On the escapes:

1. `\"` is a String escape representing one char, the double quote.
2. `\\` is the String escape representing a backslash, one char.
3. `\\\\` is the regex escape `\\` to represent the backslash itself instead of being a regex escape sequence itself.
4. If you ever want to replace backslashes, first attempt it without regex: `s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");` doubles every backslash. Guess how that is written in regex with `replaceAll`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer! but the backslash has to be followeb by one other backslash or the char "   not by any char!

Comment: @Shinon so no \t \r \n? Added that case

Comment: exactly only \\ or \" are allowed if i write  as argument "\hello" the output should be "unmatched lexeme". even if i write as argument "\\hello\\\\\"" the output should be \hello\\"

Comment: No idea, a simple `"\"ab\\\"cdef\"".matches("\"(\\\\[\"\\\\]|[^\"\\\\])*\"")` works. But in your code probably additional parentheses are needed ...|( my regex )| ... .